# When drawing two circles live view shows strange image

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift-playground

I need to draw 2 (with 1 I have the same problem) in Swift PlayGrounds on iPad. But when it is running I have very strange [result](https://share.icloud.com/photos/07FHaLggFkFU1y79FCrA2rICw)

```
class GameScene: SKScene{
var player = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 0.1)
var earth = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 0.01)

override func didMove(to view: SKView){
    //physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -0.9)

    player.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)

    player.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    player.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    player.physicsBody?.mass = 1

    earth.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX , y: player.position.y - 0.5)
    earth.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 20.0)
    earth.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    earth.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

    player.fillColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9254902005195618, green: 0.23529411852359772, blue: 0.10196078568696976, alpha: 1.0)
    earth.fillColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.34117648005485535, green: 0.6235294342041016, blue: 0.16862745583057404, alpha: 1.0)

    addChild(earth)
    addChild(player)
}
```

}

Comment: you are using a circle of radius < 1 point........so player and earth won't exist.  Who knows how fill is going to behave with such a minute body.  Your physics body however is larger than your earth, not sure what that is going to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all they are very small and perhaps you cannot see them for that reason alone.
Secondly, I guess you need to define `lineWidth` and `strokeColor` too.